# How to run migration in C#.NET project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I have project that works with SQL server. In `Models` directory I have migrtions files like as one:

```
public partial class UserData : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.confirmation_code",
                c => new
                    {
                        sys_id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        resource_id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        code = c.String(maxLength: 64),
                        user_id = c.Long(nullable: false),
                        id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        edit_date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.sys_id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.user", t => t.user_id, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.user_id);
....
```

For development I use VisualStudio, how to run all migration to deploy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should open the Nuget Management Console and type `update-database` command with migration name, and additional parameters if they are needed. Depending on your setup you might need to provide connection string name and/or project where they are located.

More on this: [Entity Framework Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: In which file usually are located configurations to database connection? I use Entity Faramework

Comment: Usually in `.config` file, either `web.config` or `app.config`

Comment: It gives me error: `Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'WebApplication'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).`

Comment: then it means that you need to specify the project with migrations by using `-ProjectName` option

Comment: @Darama my connectionString is set in appsettings.development file.